# VHDL pattern detector

Tags: vhdl

I have modified my code to the following to generate 0.5 Mhz clock from 50Mhz incoming clock I have used synchronous counter clock enable and detecting the 00110001 pattern on the din input data and output the sync pulse as shown in image . but I want dout to be at the same time as it detects the last bit in the pattern. Please check my code below and let me know where I am going wrong. I really appreciate your help. Thank you.[image]

```
pattern_detector_clk_0_5mhz : process(clk_50mhz)
begin
if clk_50mhz'event and clk_50mhz = '1' then
    if rst = '0' then
    clk_enable_0_5mhz <= '0';
    temp1 <= (others => '0');
  else
            temp1 <= temp1 +"1";
            clk_enable_0_5mhz <= '0';
        if temp1 >= x"63" then      --hexadecimal value for 99
            temp1 <= (others => '0');
            clk_enable_0_5mhz <= not clk_enable_0_5mhz;
        end if;             
     end if;
  end if;
end process;

  decoder_shift_reg_proc: process (clk_50mhz)
  begin
  if clk_50mhz'event and clk_50mhz = '1' then
     if rst = '0' then
        decoder_shift8 <= (others => '0');
     elsif clk_enable_0_5mhz = '1' then
            for i in 0 to 6 loop 
            decoder_shift8(i+1) <= decoder_shift8(i);
        end loop;        
        decoder_shift8(0) <= din;
     end if;
  end if;
end process;

sync_detector_process: process(decoder_shift8) 
begin
 if decoder_shift8 = PATTERN_TO_DETECT or decoder_shift8 = not PATTERN_TO_DETECT then
            sync_detected <= '1';
        else
            sync_detected <= '0';
end if;
end process;
```

Comment: format the code properly

Comment: the problem with your code is that you still use 50MHz clock to check the pattern, your second proccess should be invoked only on clk_enable_0_5mhz and rst

Comment: Thanks gawi, when I use just clk_enable_0_5mhz in the second process and implement the code then I am getting the following WARNING:Route:455 - CLK Net:clk_enable_0_5mhz_OBUF may have excessive skew because

Comment: If I were you I would change my design for a shift register instead a state machine. It'll be less code and easier to understand. Basicly, on each rising edge, you could rotate the bits in your SR and set the value of your first shift register to that of your input  (din). When the content of the SR correspond to your desired pattern, you just have to set your output to logic '1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is, that your enable signal is to long! set the enable signal only for one clock cycle!

```
   ...  
   clk_enable_0_5mhz<='0'; -- clear enable by default

   if temp >= x"31" then
        temp <= (others => '0');
        clk_enable_0_5mhz <= '1';-- set enable only for one clock cycle
   end if;
   ...
```

you don't need to add the enable signal to your sensitivity list, as the process will run synchronous to your clock signal anyway (except if reset asynchronously).

```
process(clk_50mhz, rst)
begin
   if(rst = '0') then
      ...
   elsif (clk_50mhz'event and clk_50mhz = '1') then
      if(clk_enable_0_5mhz = '1') then
         ...
```

here's the testbench I used

```
-- testbench
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity pattern_tb is
end pattern_tb;

architecture Behavior of pattern_tb is

component clk0_5mhz_top 
port (

        clk_50mhz : in  std_logic;
        rst : in std_logic;
        din : IN std_logic;
        dout : OUT std_logic;
        clk_enable_0_5mhz : inout std_logic
        );

end component;

signal clk_50mhz :   std_logic;
signal rst :  std_logic;
signal din :  std_logic;
signal dout :  std_logic;
signal clk_enable_0_5mhz :  std_logic;

constant pattern: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0):="00110001";
begin

uut: clk0_5mhz_top 
port map(
        clk_50mhz => clk_50mhz,
        rst => rst,
        din => din,
        dout => dout,
        clk_enable_0_5mhz => clk_enable_0_5mhz
        );

gen_clk: process
begin
    clk_50mhz<='0';
    wait for 10 ns;
    clk_50mhz<='1';
    wait for 10 ns;
end process;

gen_sigs: process
begin
    rst<='0';
    din<=pattern(7);
    wait for 10 us;
    rst<='1';
    wait for 10 us;
    for i in 7 downto 0 loop
        wait until falling_edge(clk_enable_0_5mhz);
        din<=pattern(i);
    end loop;
    wait;
end process;

end Behavior;
```

Comment: Thanks baldyHDL, I tired to implement your suggestions but there is no output i.e. dout remained '0' all the time and there are no errors and warnings.

Comment: actually it does work! I added the testbench I used to the answer above.

Comment: baldyHDL, I think I know why it is working with your testbench because the code that you have suggested produces clk_enable_0_5mhz signal with 1us time period and each bit in your testbench is 1us length where as I need clk_enable_0_5mhz time period of 2us since it should detect the pattern 00110001 in din which contains each bit of length 2us so that's why I am not able to get the dout. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: oups... of course you have to change your counter-comperator to "if temp >= x"63" then"... AND you have to increase the unsigned vector "temp" to the range (6 downto 0).

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help baldyHDL, I got the output without warnings

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. I replaced the state machine by a 8 bits shift register. I think it's cleaner.

```
library ieee;

use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;


entity clk0_5mhz_top is
port (
        clk_50mhz : in  std_logic;
        rst : in std_logic;
        din : in std_logic;
        dout : out std_logic;
        clk_enable_0_5mhz : out std_logic
);
end clk0_5mhz_top;

architecture behavioral of clk0_5mhz_top is

    constant PATTERN_TO_DETECT : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "00110001";
    signal din_sr8 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

    signal clk_5_mhz : std_logic;
    signal counter : unsigned(5 downto 0);

begin 

    --generating the synchronous counter clock enable
    p_5mhz_clk_generator : process(clk_50mhz, rst)
    begin

        clk_enable_0_5mhz <= clk_5_mhz;

        if(rst = '0') then
            clk_5_mhz <= '0';
            counter <= (others => '0');

        elsif(rising_edge(clk_50mhz)) then
            counter <= counter +"1";

            if counter >= x"31" then --49
                counter <= (others => '0');
                clk_5_mhz <= '1';
           else
                clk_5_mhz <= '0';
           end if;

      end if;

    end process;

    --generating 00110001 pattern detector
    p_pattern_detector : process(clk_5_mhz, rst)
    begin
        if(rst = '0') then
            dout <= '0';
            din_sr8 <= "XXXXXXXX";
        elsif (clk_5_mhz='1') then
            for i in 0 to 6 loop --register shifter
                din_sr8(i+1) <= din_sr8(i);
            end loop;        

            din_sr8(0) <= din;

            if din_sr8 = PATTERN_TO_DETECT then
                dout <= '1';
            else
                dout <= '0';
            end if;

        end if;

    end process;

end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Passepartout. I am able to get the output i.e dout goes high at the same rising edge of the clock as the last bit '1' of pattern 00110001 is detected. How can I get dout to go high in the next rising edge of clk_enable_0_5mhz after whole pattern is detected??                                                                   I am still getting this warning should I ignore this warning?                                        WARNING:Route:455 - CLK Net:clk_enable_0_5mhz_OBUF may have excessive skew because 0 CLK pins and 2 NON_CLK pins failed to route using a CLK template.

Comment: You just have to clock your output assignment to have an additional delay. I edited my code to solve that. Also, your warning is almost surely caused by the fact that your clock is an inout signal, which almost should never be used. If you need an output that you also need to use internally, you should create another signal. I also made that correction. You shouldn't get any warning now.

Comment: Thanks a lot Passepartout you have been very helpful. I got the output that I need but with the warning??                      WARNING:Route:455 - CLK Net:clk_5_mhz may have excessive skew because 0 CLK pins and 2 NON_CLK pins failed to route using a CLK template.

Comment: Hmm I think your routing software doesn't like the rising edge on a signal other than the master clock. I'm not sure how to solve that problem. In any case, it's not recommended to have two different clock frequency in your designs, especially if one of them is generated by your FPGA logic and not by the board oscillator. If you need to do a particular action at a certain interval (say 1/50 clock cycles), you should use an internal counter for each block that needs it.

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need clk_enable_0_5mhz as inout? maybe signal will be enough?
Of course you should initialize it at the beginning:

```
signal clk_enable_0_5mhz: std_logic := '0';
```

then the beginning of the process should look like (remove one of the if statements):

```
process(clk_enable_0_5mhz, rst)
begin
    if(rst = '0') then
        dout <= '0';
        state <= A;
    elsif (clk_enable_0_5mhz'event and clk_enable_0_5mhz = '1') then
```

I hope this would help.

Comment: this kind of design is not good practice! it will let the synthesizer treat the clk_enable_0_5mhz signal as a clock instead of an enable. user24883's initial approach was better as it is truely synchronous to ONE clock.